# How to reparticipate in torrent seeding?

Tags: bittorrent

I have a file which was downloaded from torrent tracker. How to find it on tracker or how to reparticipate in seeding?

Comment: You need to the torrent file.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the torrent is still seeded:

1. Obtain the torrent file from the original source, another torrent site or the cache folder of your torrent client (%appdata%/uTrorrent or similar)
2. Load the file in the client and direct it to save the media in the directory where the downloaded files reside.
3. Instruct the torrent client to re-validate downloaded data.

Comment: The problem is to find torrent file. There are millions of them on tracker and there are none of them on my computer. Re-creating file from scratch didn't help.